# Look up College name from email address

Tags: php, mysql

this may be out of the realm of stackoverflow, but I have a problem. I am trying to automatically insert the name of the College/University every one of my signups attends. They can only use a .edu email to signup and I was wondering If there were a way to see the College or University the email belonged to?

Ex:

morris@uakron.edu

Would return:

The University of Akron

Or does someone know where I could find such a directory?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry yes, requests for a directory like this is off-topic.

Comment: I actually have seen a project in GitHub that does exactly this. I'll try to find it and post it ...

Comment: I've updated the title to match the question

Comment: The "registrant" part of a whois query on the domain name?

Comment: @user1759682 I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate a MySQL table with all the university names and their email domains. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022442/evaluating-a-string-in-php) is a sample directory that you can perhaps start with.

Once you've done that, you can parse the user's email for the domain. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6917269/924643) is a very similar answer on how to get the domain name from an email address.

Once you have got the domain from the user's email, retrieve the university/college's name from the MySQL database. (If it does not exist, it's worth logging since it could be a new domain name that is not in your database yet)

Answer (score 1):

[**Swot**](https://github.com/leereilly/swot) is a project (written in Ruby) that does exactly that. It checks that if a given email belongs to an educational institute (using a database filled with domain-names mapped to institute names).

> Swot allows you to identify whether a particular email address or
>   domain is associated with an academic institution providing higher
>   education in tertiary, quaternary or post-secondary education in any
>   country in the world.

You probably can utilize some parts of it in your code (Swot's database by itself is a great treasure).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to looking it up in a table is to do a who-is search on the domain the email came from to find who it is registered to.

You can use a service like [WhoisAPI](http://whoisxmlapi.com/) to make the API calls and then parse the output for the registrant name. Might not always give exactly what you want, though.